# java private members call by reference

Tags: java

```
class insertionSort
{
    public void print(int arr[])
    {   
        arr[0]=999999999;
    }
}

public class Sorting 
{
    private  int[] arr=   {0,56,8,75,45,21,68,9,54,2,65,87,52,65,8,5,20,0,2,2};

    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        Sorting sort = new Sorting();
        insertionSort inSort = new insertionSort();
        inSort.print(sort.arr);
        System.out.println(sort.arr[0]);
    }
}
```

Although Sort.arr is a private variable , why  inSort object is able to manipulate arr[0] ?

I know the parameter is passing by reference or address.

In a function how can I pass by value ?

Comment: output is : 999999999

Comment: Java is always pass by value, however `arr` is a reference, and this reference is passed by value.  You don't get the array copied.

Comment: but the original Sort object arr[] value is changed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value will answer your question

Comment: You didn't create a copy of it and it won't automagically copy it for you. It will create a copy of the reference to the array, but there is only one array.

Comment: arrays are actually pointers ---
 
`arr[]` is internally  `*(arr+0)`  ---

`arr` is just the address of first element `&arr[0]`  ----

when you pass `arr` you are actually passing address of the first element (pass by reference);

So what ever Changes you make will be made on that memory directly

Comment: The value is the int[] references. So you are accessing the same object, that why I prefer to write `int[] arr` to see that I pass an array and not a integer.

Comment: @mohanenb so, how can I pass this array "by values" ? or copied array

Comment: create a copy of that array and send it to the functions ---cause in java all object and array variables are reference variables

Comment: @markrotteveel: No, this is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value. Despite appearances, the question isn't about pass-by-value/pass-by-reference at all.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder IMHO that is the basic issue of this question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: No. The question is asking how the array entry can be changed by code that isn't in the class where the `arr` member is declared, even though `arr` is `private`. The OP mentioned pass-by-value, etc., but is mistaken about that. It's about object references, nothing to do with passing conventions at all.

Answer (score 2):

> In a function how can I pass by value?

Java is **always** pass-by-value, never pass-by-reference (see [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)). The value being passed in your example is the object reference<sup>1</sup> that points to the array.

Your issue has nothing to do with pass-by-value vs. pass-by-reference, it has to do with that fact that you're passing an object reference (which is a value) into a method. That gives the method access to the object that reference refers to. So naturally it can modify the state of that object; in your case, it can modify what's stored at index 0 of the array.

Separately, it doesn't matter that the instance variable (field) you're getting that object reference from is `private`; the code `inSort.print(sort.arr);` is in the `Sorting` class, so it has access to `sort.arr`, reads its value (an object reference), and passes that value (the object reference) into the method.

---

<sup>1</sup> It's important to realize that the word "reference" in "object reference" and "pass-by-reference" is talking about **two very different things**. In "object reference" it's talking about a reference to an object (a pointer to it). In "pass-by-reference" it's talking about a reference (pointer) to a **variable**. Java doesn't have pass-by-reference.